# Nextcloud on ubuntu server 19.04

Tags: 19.04

I have recently Installed Ubuntu 19.04 server with Nextcloud but can not find the location of config file.

I need to edit nextcloud config file to add trusted IP

Thx

Comment: Can you please list the version and the type of NextCloud installation you have setup.  Is it a Docker install?  Is it a Snap install?  Is it a manual install?  Are you using a reverse proxy?  If you can provide more information about the installation method, then we can point out where the config files are.  It may also be wise to bring this up on the NextCloud forums, as it relates to instructions they provide.

Answer (score 0):

The config file is "config.php", and its location depends on how exactly you installed Nextcloud.  If you installed it via snap the location is:

```
/var/snap/nextcloud/current/nextcloud/config/config.php
```

I did a beginner's video on setting up Nextcloud on my YouTube channel.

https://youtu.be/IFPqedkW0aI

If you can't find it you could try using locate to find it.

```
sudo updatedb

locate config.php | grep nextcloud
```

**Edit in response to your question about switching versions of the Nextcloud snap.**

To use a different version of the Nextcloud snap you can use the "switch" command. You can see the different versions available, as well as additional information about the version you have installed, by running:

`snap info nextcloud`

On my system it shows the newest version that isn't listed as a non-RC version is in the 16/edge channel, so you can switch with:

`sudo snap switch --channel 16/edge nextcloud`

After changing channels you "might", or might not, need to manually refresh your snap packages to get it to actually update, so if it doesn't seem to do anything after you change channels, you can try and force it to update to the new version with:

`sudo snap refresh nextcloud`

Comment: Dear Gerown, than you and glad you answer. yes it is located /var/snap/nextcloud/current/nextcloud/config/config.php.

Comment: I have find your video very very helpful. Thx for the G8 job. I have another question you may help. I have freenas and need to use that server as storage for nextcloud on ubuntu 19.04. what is the best way to do so..

Comment: oh yes have another question. Ubuntu 19.04 nextcloud is release 15 but they have 16.1 how can I upgrade...

Comment: I edited my original answer above to explain how to switch channels for a snap package, in this case, to use version 16 of the Nextcloud server snap.

As far as using your FreeNAS as the storage location, I would think that as long as you make sure it's "mounted" properly, so that it looks like a local drive, you should be able to apply the same directions for changing storage location.  I'm not sure though as I've got limited experience with FreeNAS, so I'm not sure if it's a separate device from your server, if you're using one "as" the server, how it's mounted, etc.

Comment: Thx again. The freenas is on another machine on same network as server with samba enabled.

Comment: Just an FYI, after you switch channels, you "might" have to run sudo snap refresh to get it to update to the newer version.  You might not, but if it doesn't seem to do anything after switching channels, try manually running sudo snap refresh.